# Create collection of objects with Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, grouping

Basically, I have an array with objects and they would need to be grouped together. It is kinda hard to explain, but it might be easier if I just gave you guys an example.

**Result data**

```
[
 {
  "Category": "Préparé",
  "Sandwich": "Martino",
  "Ingredient": "Ansjovis",
  "Price": 3.1
 },
 {
  "Category": "Préparé",
  "Sandwich": "Martino",
  "Ingredient": "Tabasco",
  "Price": 3.1
 },
 {
  "Category": "Veggie",
  "Sandwich": "Gezond",
  "Ingredient": "Tomaat",
  "Price": 2.5
 },
 {
  "Category": "Veggie",
  "Sandwich": "Gezond",
  "Ingredient": "Kaas",
  "Price": 2.5
 }
];
```

This is a basic example of what my array looks like. I cannot change this structure, it is how our API provides the data.

What I actually need is this structure:

```
[
 {
  "CategoryName": "Prépare",
  "Sandwiches": [
    {
     "SandwichName": "Martino",
     "Price": 3.1,
     "Ingredients": ["Ansjovis", "Tabasco"]
    }
  ]
 },
 {
  "CategoryName": "Veggie",
  "Sandwiches": [
   {
    "SandwichName": "Gezond",
    "Price": 2.5,
    "Ingredients": ["Tomaat", "Kaas"]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I have tried some stuff with Underscore and _.groupBy, _.sortBy, _.countBy
But alas, nothing I have tried actually works. Is this even possible with Underscore (or some other library)?

Also on a sidenote, this example might have some JSON structure mistakes, because I wrote it myself. The data provided by the API has a correct format.

The example only has 2 sandwiches, but in real-time, I'll be retrieving multiple categories with each 20 sandwiches and so on. This is just a minified example, but it provides an idea of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

try this in simple js

```
var map = {};
results.forEach( function(obj){
  map[ obj.CategoryName ] = map[ obj.CategoryName ] || [];
  map[ obj.CategoryName ].push( obj );
});

var output  = Object.keys(map).map( function(key){
  var arr = [];
  map[key].forEach(function(obj){
     arr.push( {
       "SandwichName": obj.SandwichName,
       "Price": obj.Price,
       "Ingredients": obj.Ingredients
     }); 
  });
  return { "CategoryName" : key , "Sandwiches" : arr };
});
```

Comment: Didn't do the trick. Got an array with all objects, same like I already have and all properties have "undefined" as value. This is assuming `objArray` is the array to pass along

Comment: What do you get in `output`

Comment: That actually works, if I change the property names (which isn't too hard), the only property that has not been filled in are the ingredients.

Comment: @Jorrex you need to use the same property names (on the right hand side) which are present in the original array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111789/discussion-between-jorrex-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code would do the trick for you:

```
var data = [...]; // this is your json-data

var result = _.map(_.uniq(_.pluck(data, 'Category')), function(category) {
    var sandwiches = _.uniq(_.pluck(_.where(data, { Category: category }), 'Sandwich'));
    return { 
        CategoryName: category, 
        Sandwiches: _.map(sandwiches, function(sandwich) {
            return { 
            SandwitchName: sandwich, 
          Price: _.findWhere(data, { Category: category, Sandwich: sandwich }).Price, 
          Ingredients: _.pluck(_.where(data, { Category: category, Sandwich: sandwich }), 'Ingredient') 
        };
        })
  };
});
```